# Unable to send header and multipart at the same time in Retrofit 2 in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

This is the code im using for multiple uploads to server.This format is working fine in POSTMAN and not working in by using retrofit2. Can anybody help me

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/answers/save")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Header("Authorization") String 
authorization,@Part("input_answer") RequestBody answer_string,@Part 
  List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
```

check this

```
@NonNull
private RequestBody createPartFromJsonString(String json_answers_string) {
    return RequestBody.create(
            okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, json_answers_string);
}
```

check this ,  using this for converting file to multipart body

```
@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String attachment_name, String absolute_path) {
 File file = new File(absolute_path);


    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(attachment_name, file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

This is used for multiple uploads

```
private void multipartUploadAudit(JSONObject json_object, List<String> FileNameWithAbsolutePath) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //convert jsonobject to string
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String answers_string_json_obj = gson.toJson(json_object);


    APIService mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
    List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    // add dynamic
    for (int i = 0; i < FileNameWithAbsolutePath.size(); i++) {
        String name = FileNameWithAbsolutePath.get(i).substring(FileNameWithAbsolutePath.get(i).lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String names[] = name.split("\\.");
        parts.add(prepareFilePart(names[0], FileNameWithAbsolutePath.get(i)));
    }
    // add another part within the multipart request
    RequestBody answer_string = createPartFromJsonString(answers_string_json_obj);

    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = mAPIService.upload("Bearer " + sharedPrefUserData.getUserData().getAuthToken(), answer_string, parts);
    // Call<ResponseBody> call = mAPIService.upload( description, parts);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                response.body(); // do something with that
                Toast.makeText(AuditQuestionsLandingScreen.this, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                response.errorBody(); // do something with that
                Toast.makeText(AuditQuestionsLandingScreen.this, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            internetConnectionChecker.serverErrorAlert();
            Log.v("Upload_error:", t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(AuditQuestionsLandingScreen.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the key of the image-list? You know, as in the postman.

Answer (score 0):

After long struggle i got my answer. i made a mistake by converting jsonobject to string by using gson. it added enveloped my string with 
 {"nameValuePairs": {}}

so i used  this. 
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-
    data"),String.valueOf(json_object))